# Object detection

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to recognize the numbers on the 7-segment LCD display(like the digital watch), and first of all I want to 'draw' a bounding box to focus on the LCD screen to get rid of most of the background noise, but I am still not sure which method is suitable for this task. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What platform are you working on?

Comment: Are you processing a photo of the LCD? Video? Is the LCD moving in the video frame, or is it always in the same place?

Comment: I am working on a app for iPhone, so it is mac based and using objective-c.

Comment: It is pictures I take from iPhone camera, so the LCD will not always the same one or in the same place of the same background, I know it is difficult to recognize every LCD, but what I want is most of them or some typical ones.

Answer (score 0):

I won't tell you the exact answer but as far as I can tell you should take a look at the [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) library. The keyword you're looking for in the first place is: `Region Of Interest (ROI)`, ie. the bounding box.